# Quiero Realizar Una búsqueda avanzada en Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Mi pregunta es ¿puede realizarse una búsqueda avanzada con Spring data JPA o a través de maneras similares?

Este tipo de consulta lo realizaba en la misma DB de postgres a través de funciones, la función realizaba la acción de llevar los dos campos a un solo campo y este lo llamaba desde otra función la cual recibía cualquier parámetro y lo comparaba con los campos nombre y apellido, quería saber si puede realizar este tipo de búsqueda desde el mismo spring sin tener que construir la función en la DB

```
package com.app.eess.per.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.app.eess.per.domain.Persona;

@Repository
public interface PersonaRepository extends JpaRepository<Persona, Long> {

    @Query("select p from Persona p where p.nombre like %?1%")//busqueda por un solo campo
    List<Persona> findByName(String nombre);

    /**busqueda por varios campos, lo que se quiere es que cuando ingrese una letra, este se búsque  
     * en los dos campos nombre y apellido no por separado la cual lo realiza la siguiente consulta

    */
    @Query("select p from Persona p where p.nombre = :nombre or p.apellido = :apellido")
    List<Persona> findByNameOrLastName(@Param("nombre") String nombre, @Param("apellido") String apellido);//se quiere que reciba solo un parámetro pero que realice la búsqueda en los dos campos

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, creo que puedes concatenar en el WHERE y comparar:

```
select p from Persona p where concat(p.nombre,' ', p.apellido) like %?1%
```

Comment: gracias si es exactamente lo que estaba buscando y funciona muy  bien @Pablo Lozano

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido, puedes extender de Repository y usarlas de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Información extraída de https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation